# Hide / View Edit view form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a small ASP.NET MVC 4 application in combination with MongoDB. Currently I have 4 views: Index, Create, List, Edit. Create is a form to put data in the database. List is a list to display the data. Edit is a form to edit the data. These three views are rendered inside the Index view (RenderAction).

The goal is to display only two views inside the index view. A combination of Index with Create, or a combination of Index with Edit.

At this moment I'm having problems with the Edit View (inside the controller):

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
                Car car = CarRentalContext.Cars.FindOneById(new ObjectId(id));
                return View(car.ConvertToUpdateViewModel());
        }
```

Edit view:

```
@model MvcApplication1.ViewModels.UpdateCarViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>UpdateCarViewModel</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Make)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Make)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Make)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NumberOfDoors)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NumberOfDoors)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NumberOfDoors)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DailyRentalFee)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DailyRentalFee)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DailyRentalFee)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Index View:

```
@model MvcApplication1.ViewModels.InsertCarViewModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        @{Html.RenderAction("Create", Model);}
    </div>

    <div>
        @{Html.RenderAction("List", Model);}
    </div>

    <div>
        @{Html.RenderAction("Edit", Model);}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Obviously the Edit view needs an ID to display, and it gets an error now when I use `RenderAction`, because there is no ID when I start the application. I want to hide this view when it is not needed, and only display this view when it is needed. How can I achive this without Javascript / Jquery.

Do I need  an if/else statement inside my `ActionResult`?

Comment: Could you post your existing `View`

Comment: I have edited my question. In my Index View I have 3 div's, In each div there is a `@{Html.RenderAction("View", Model);}`

Comment: I wanted to see your `Index` view, apologies.

Comment: what error/problem are you having?

Comment: If I understand your requirement properly, yes you can do this without JavaScript but to do so you will require a fairly detailed knowledge of CSS.  Without that, jomsk1e's answer will allow you to navigate to an edit page for the record of your choice, which is about as good as ASP.NET can do without augmented HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and quickest thing to do would be to just check if `id` has a value

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
    {
        return null;
    }

    Car car = CarRentalContext.Cars.FindOneById(new ObjectId(id));
    return View(car.ConvertToUpdateViewModel());
}
```

Comment: I have tried this code, and it does works. But when I input data with the Create form, and I leave the fields empty, the validation makes sure the data does not get into the data base. This works correct. But the Edit form does display when I click on that same button. I think it is because it gets an ID?

Answer (score 0):

That's not a problem, in MVC Edit Controller typically has an id param, so to eliminate your problem you can just check if id is existing, something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
{
        Car car = CarRentalContext.Cars.FindOneById(new ObjectId(id));

        if (car != null)
        {
            return View(car.ConvertToUpdateViewModel());
        }

        //if we get this far show other view
        return View();
}
```